# Microsoft Dynamics Nav Post using Web Services

Tags: c#, web-services, navision

Im trying to Post on Navision using Navision Web Services (using C#) but so far looks impossible, especially since I dont own developer license. But there are some Codeunits like Codeunit 22,23 which are supposed to do the post of Item Journals but I cant seem to make them work and cant find good info about how to do that. Any little help will be much more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to publish those codeunits and try post like this then it is not good approach. And "cant seem to make them work" is just not enough to help you.

Most of customer licenses include free objects that can be created and modified w/o dev license. Those should have numbers starting from 50000 in object designer. I would advise you to create and publish codeunit within this range and call it from your application as web service.

In the codeunit you put creating and/or posting of journal lines. Calling posting codeunits from there should be no problem. But choosing of proper codeunit to call heavily depends on what exactly you are trying to post and what results you expect.